# How keep same number of digits when dividing variable python

Tags: python, math, decimal, operation

When dividing a number, I loose one digit. This extra digit is important since I'm playing with coordinates and the precision drops considerably.

Find the example below:

```
gt2['message_basicContainer_reference_position_latitude']
Out[107]: 
0       414049364.0
Name: message_basicContainer_reference_position_latitude, Length: 1785, dtype: float64

gt2['message_basicContainer_reference_position_latitude']/10000000
Out[108]: 
0       41.404936
Name: message_basicContainer_reference_position_latitude, Length: 1785, dtype: float64
```

How can I keep the last digit? In this example is the 4.

Comment: Share your actual code, please.  If I just run `414049364.0 / 10000000` I get `41.4049364`.  Something in your code is rounding it off after it's been divided.

Comment: Please note that what is printed to console is not the same as what is held in memory. (the printing is usually truncated)

Comment: Simple default printing won't round it off that much though -- if you do e.g. `f"{414049364.0 / 10000000}"` you get `'41.4049364'`  So there's something in their code that's specifically chopping it off at that number of digits.